# Loading screen coverd by the footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a loading screen on my personal website. I found that the footer will cover my loading screen when I go into the website.

I want my loading screen can cover the entire screen when I go into the website. How can I do that?

This is my code, css and js.

```
<footer class="cfooter navbar-fixed-bottom text-center" id="cfooter">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">Powered by <a href="https://www.test.com/" target="_blank">User</a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

#cfooter {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid 000000; 
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
}

div.load_screen {
        position:fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: white;
    }

img.load_screen {
        z-index: 9999999;
        position: fixed;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        margin: -27px 0 0 -95px; /* -image-height/2 0 0 -image-width/2 */
        background: white;
    }

$(function() {
        $("div.load_screen").fadeIn("slow")
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("div.load_screen").fadeOut("slow")
        }, 3000);
    })
```

Comment: try adding `top:0;` and `left:0;` and `z-index:1000;` to `div.load_screen`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add #cfooter {z-index: 1}
and add top and left 0.

```
div.load_screen {
        position:fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: red;
        top: 0;
        left:0;
    }
```

Here is the working example. I have added red background just to test it:
https://jsfiddle.net/o7wd4mfp/4/

Answer (score 1):

add `z-index: 999;` to `div.load_screen`